# Allowing Specific File Types to be Uploaded in PHP Email Forms

Tags: php, forms, file, email, upload

I am creating a php form. I would like to allow users to upload either mp3 files, pdfs, pngs or jpgs. All other aspects of the form seems to work; however, the attachments come through as 0 kb. In my php.ini, I have a large file size limit. Below is the code I am using:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //The form has been submitted, prep a nice thank you message
    $output = '<h3>Thank you for your submission!</h3>';
    //Set the form flag to no display 
    $flags = 'style="display:none;"';

    //Email
    $to = 'info@music-scribes.com';
    $subject=" $servicetype Music Scribes Inquiry";

    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $servicetype=$_REQUEST['servicetype'];
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    $attachment = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

    $headers = "From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";
    $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

    --_1_$boundary
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

    --_2_$boundary
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    Service Type: $servicetype
    Message: $message 

    --_2_$boundary--
    --_1_$boundary
    Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3, application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/png; name=\"$file\" 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment 

    $attachment
    --_1_$boundary--";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>MailFile</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php echo $output; ?>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" <?php echo $flags;?>>
    <font size=2>

    <p><label for="name">Name<font color=red>*</font></label><br><input type="name" name="name" required><br><br>
    <p><label for="email">Email<font color=red>*</font></label><br><input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>

    Transcription Service Type:
    <select name="servicetype">
    <option value="Transcription">Transcription</option>
    <option value="Arrangement">Arrangement</option>
    <option value="Scoring">Scoring</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <p><label for="message">Message<font color=red>*</font></label><br>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="8" required>
    </textarea></p><br>

    <p><label for="file">Upload File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please let me know what I must change in order for mp3 uploads, pdfs and images all work through the form.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the files are properly uploaded yet adding them to your e-mail message won't work?

I suggest using a third party library to make things easier. PHP's mail function works fine if you want to send a simple e-mail message but things are getting slightly more complicated if you want to send an attachment or use HTML in your e-mail. Of course it's possible but libraries like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) make things a lot easier.

On it's Github page there's a whole example on how to use it. To add an attachment, you can just use `$email->AddAttachment('path/to/file.type', 'fileName.type');`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you uploading your file? I don't see any file upload handling.
Look at this example: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) (especially at the **move_uploaded_file** part).

Why are you mixing REQUEST and POST superglobals in your code? You have `$_REQUEST['email']` but `$_POST['message']`. If all the data comes from post request, change all the `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`.